# Asynchronous callback in D3.js

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, callback, asynccallback

I'm working on a visualization in D3 and I'm still in the learning process (JS included) and I want to remove the duplicated code from `maxExportYears` and `maxImportYears`.

```
function calcMaximum(json) {

   let maxExportYears = json.map(function (obj) {
      let maxByYear = [];
      obj.entries.map( function(entry) {
          maxByYear.push(parseFloat(entry.exported));
      });
      return d3.max(maxByYear, function(d) { return d; });
   });

  /// calculate the maximum Export across all years
  let maxExport = d3.max(maxExportYears, function(d) {return d;} );

  /// calculate the maximum Import on each year
  let maxImportYears = json.map(function (obj) {
      let maxByYear = [];
      obj.entries.map( function(entry) {
          maxByYear.push(parseFloat(entry.imported));
      });
      return d3.max(maxByYear, function(d) { return d; });
  });

  /// calculate the maximum Import across all years
  let maxImport = d3.max(maxImportYears, function(d) {return d;} );


  /// calculate the maximum between maxExport and maxImport
  let maximum = d3.max([maxExport, maxImport], function(d) {return d;});
  return maximum;
}

 d3.json('/file_name.json', function(error, json) {
    if (error) throw error;
    let data = json;

    let maximum =  calcMaximum(data);
    let scaleRadius = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, maximum]).range([0,150]); 
}
```

I have created the following function to replace the duplicated code:

```
function calculateMaxByYear(json, activity) {
  json.map(function (obj) {
    let maxByYear = [];
      obj.entries.map( function(entry) {
        maxByYear.push(parseFloat(entry[activity]));
      })
      let maximus = d3.max(maxByYear, function(d) { return d; });
    return maximus;
  })
};
```

which in a synchronous way might be called `calculateMaxByYear(json, 'imported');` `calculateMaxByYear(json, 'exported');`, but I don't know how to use it in an asynchronous way.

Any ideas on how to solve this are very welcomed!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does this have to do with async? I don't see it. Aren't you just going to do `let maxExportYears = calculateMaxByYear(json, 'exported');` ?

Comment: `d3.json` is asynchronous,
`let maxExportYears = calculateMaxByYear(json, 'exported');` returns `undefined`

Comment: Sure, but not the function you created.

Comment: So the code from `calcMaximum` works, the only thing I want to do is to refactor it so I don't have duplicated code, and I don't know how to do that. I thought that creating a function like `calculateMaxByYear` might help, but I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you think the problem is more complicated than it is, or I am misunderstanding the issue.

First of all you need to fix your function to return the result of the `.map` operation:

```
function calculateMaxByYear(json, activity) {
    return json.map(...);
//  ^^^^^^
}
```

And then you simply replace the existing code with a call to this function:

```
function calcMaximum(json) {

  let maxExportYears = calculateMaxByYear(json, 'exported');
  // call function     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  let maxExport = d3.max(maxExportYears, function(d) {return d;} );
  let maxImportYears = calculateMaxByYear(json, 'imported');
  // call function     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  let maxImport = d3.max(maxImportYears, function(d) {return d;} );
  let maximum = d3.max([maxExport, maxImport], function(d) {return d;});

  return maximum;
}
```

However, the whole can be simplified to

```
function calcMaximum(json) {
  return d3.max(
    calculateMaxByYear(json, 'exported')
      .concat(calculateMaxByYear(json, 'imported'))
  );
}
```

There is no need for all this intermediate values and there is no need to pass a callback to `d3.max`. The identify function is basically the default callback.

---

As I said in my comments, the fact that `d3.json` is asynchronous has no impact on how `calculateMaxByYear` is called.

Comment: Thank you so much, returning the result from the map function solved the issue. And yeah, I think I overcomplicated the solution in my head.